# How to transform data in nested way using Jolt spec in nifi?

Tags: json, apache-nifi, jolt

I want this data to be transformed in a given way using the jolt spec of Nifi.

Condition is if `studentId`, `loc_id` and `topId` are the same then we will combine their info and will pass the rest as it is.

**Data**

```json
[
  {
    "studentId": "2222",
    "loc_id": "L1",
    "topId": "Lotus",
    "SubID1": "A1",
    "SubID2": "B1"
  },
  {
    "studentId": "2222",
    "loc_id": "L1",
    "topId": "Lotus",
    "SubID1": "A2",
    "SubID2": ""
  },
  {
    "studentId": "3333",
    "loc_id": "L3",
    "topId": "Rose",
    "SubID1": "A3",
    "SubID2": ""
  },
  {
    "studentId": "4444",
    "loc_id": "L3",
    "topId": "tulip",
    "SubID1": "A5",
    "SubID2": "B7"
  }
]
```

**Data after jolt spec:** First two data have same studentId, loc_id and topId so we have to combine their info and rest two have passed as it is with an addition of visit list.

```json
[
  {
    "studentId": "2222",
    "loc_id": "L1",
    "topId": "Lotus",
    "VisitList": [
      {
        "SubID1": "A1",
        "SubID2": "B1"
      },
      {
        "SubID1": "A2",
        "SubID2": ""
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "studentId": "3333",
    "loc_id": "L3",
    "topId": "Rose",
    "VisitList": [
      {
        "SubID1": "A3",
        "SubID2": ""
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "providerId": "4444",
    "specillity": "L3",
    "topId": "tulip",
    "VisitList": [
      {
        "SubID1": "A5",
        "SubID2": "B7"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following transformation

```json
[
  { // group by those three attributes
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": "@1,studentId.@1,loc_id.@1,topId.&",
        "S*": "@1,studentId.@1,loc_id.@1,topId.VisitList[&1].&"
      }
    }
  },
  { // get rid of the wrappers
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": {
          "*": {
            "@": ""
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "cardinality",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": "ONE", // pick only single one from repeating components 
        "VisitList": "MANY"
      }
    }
  },
  { // get rid of the generated nulls within "VisitList" arrays 
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "*": "=recursivelySquashNulls"
    }
  }
]
```

the ***demo*** on the site http://jolt-demo.appspot.com/ is

[image]